# Function to read role, environment file in masterless puppet

Tags: ruby, puppet

I'm working with Puppet 4.5 in masterless configuration and am trying to create a Puppet function to read a simple config file that assigns roles and environments. I don't have any integration with hiera/facter that I can change.

The file format is:

```
host1::java_app_node::qa
host2::nodejs_app_node::prod
```

The Puppet function that will read this file is in a module called `homebase`. I want to function to return a hash or array of hashes that split the config values. This will let me use them in templates.

In `modules/homebase/manifests/init.pp` I define:

```
$role_file = 'puppet://role.lst'
```

I then created `modules/homebase/functions/get_roles.pp` as follows:

```
function homebase::get_roles() {
    $func_name = 'homebase::get_roles()'

    if ! File.exists?($::homebase::role_file) {
        fail("Could not find #{$::homebase::role_file}")
    }

    hosts = { }
    File.open($::homebase::role_file).each |line| {
        parts = line.split(/::/)
        hosts[parts[0]] = { 'host' => parts[0], 'role' => parts[1], 'env' => parts[2] }
    }
    return hosts
}
```

In other classes, I then want to call:

```
class myapp {
    $servers = homebase::get_roles().each | k, v | { 
         $v['host'] if $v['role'] =~ /myapp/ && $v['env'] == $environment
    }    

    file { 'myapp.cfg':
        ensure => file,
        path => '/opt/myapp/myapp.cfg',
        source => template("/myapp/myapp.cfg.erb"),
        mode => '0644',
        owner => myuser,
        group => myuser,
    }

}
```

Seems like there would be a better way to do this. Am I completely off base?

Comment: Masterless and no ability to change Facter or Hiera? This seems a reasonable alternative to me given those harsh limitations.

Comment: @MattSchuchard - I'm somewhat new to puppet. Is there some way I can use hiera/factor from within my git repo and independently of the default system config (/etc/puppet.conf)?

Comment: Yes: you can use external and custom facts. Also, if you are on a non-ancient version of Puppet (>= 4.3), you can use Hiera module data. Note that module data is not "production ready" until Puppet 4.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There turned out to be a much easier way to this rather than try to create a function to read a non-standard configuration file. Instead, I used a `site.pp` file to create `node {}` entries. I also parameterized the `myapp` class to take inputs based on the node.

So my `site.pp` looks like:

```
node 'server1.mydomain', 'server2.mydomain' {
  $myvar = [ 'val1', 'val2' ]
  class { 'myapp':
     values => $myvar
  }
}
```

This could probably be improved. One of the issues is with a non-Puppet configuration file I was able to also able to control execution in my bash wrapper script. Much of the need for that went away when, though, with the node definitions.